# How can I make an image refresh everytime it is called on a page

Tags: php, image, caching

By default when a webpage is loaded, images are loaded one single time for each image. If you have 5 instances of the same image on a page, that image is loaded once, and then used in all 5 places seemingly from the cache of the first image load.

What I want to do is have a single image displayed 5 times on a page, and each time the images is called have it re-loaded.

The reason for this is I have an image that is called from a database and each time the image is called it loads a different picture. Now this works perfectly when refeshing the page, but not when the image is loaded multiple times on the same page.

For example if I put the following into a webpage:

```
<img src='http://bannerpillar.com/u/viraladmin.jpg'>
```

The image loads perfectly. If I reload the page, a different picture is displayed for each time the page reloads. However if I add the image to a page in 2 different locations, the same one picture is displayed from both locations.

How can I make it so the image is refreshed every time it is called on a page? Is that possible?

Comment: Add a unique GET string to it's URL, e.g., `http://yoursite.com/your/img.jpg?r=jfkd949ckdkd`. Make it different for each one.

Comment: what is the database call look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something to the end of the file reference, like this:

```
<img src='http://bannerpillar.com/u/viraladmin.jpg?<?=rand(11111,99999)?>'>
```

The browser will think each image is unique and load each one separately rather than using the image from cache.

Comment: This is commonly known as a cache-buster.

Comment: Thanks for the information, next time I research I will search cache buster :)

Comment: what if this is an base64 src?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a tutorial on this exact question here:
http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/php_random_image_rotation.html

Basically, in the src, you call a php file. The php file loads a filename from a directory of images.

For your case, you would need to write some logic to offset the database return, so this becomes a mysql question as well?

If you wanted the markup to call for an image file, you could redirect using a .htaccess rewriterule

Answer (score 0):

Random no. generetion can be a good option.
but more better if you load those images serially i.e. one after another
n u can use looping for that.

Answer (score -1):

Add a ?rand= to the image url.

```
<img src='http://bannerpillar.com/u/viraladmin.jpg?rand=<?php echo rand(100000,999999); ?>'>
```

Comment: This was definitely the answer to what I asked, unfortunately it did what I wanted to well, and it doesn't seem what I wanted will be possible but I thank you for this answer, I was able to paste this code and test it out and see for myself what the problem's that arose would be.

Unfortunately I am using a service that rotates images and url's. Everytime a image is loaded, the forwarding url linked to the image changes. So when I loaded the image 4 times on a page, the only link that was being forwarded to was the link of the final image.

None the less thank you again.